# To check who has updated my database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have server database MySQL which is connected to different network(or ip address) 
i want to find out which user has updated what and when ?

can log file help me in this if so how ?

please can anyone update me in this?

Answer (score 1):

You should activate the general log. Normally, the general is a text file. I have posts that show you how to make the general log a MyISAM table. Then, you could query the general log by datetime using SQL.

Here are my posts how to setup and configure the general log as a MyISAM table

- `Jun 30, 2011` : [How do I output MySQL logs to syslog?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3552/how-do-i-output-mysql-logs-to-syslog/3571#3571)
- `Jan 08, 2012` : [How to enable MySQL general log?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10329/how-to-enable-mysql-general-log/10346#10346)
- `Feb 11, 2012` : [MySQL general log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12667/mysql-general-log/12672#12672)
- `Apr 04, 2013` : [Stress test MySQL with queries captured with general log in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39221/stress-test-mysql-with-queries-captured-with-general-log-in-mysql/39285#39285)
- `Jun 23, 2013` : [Analyse MySQL General Query Log in Real-time?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45105/analyse-mysql-general-query-log-in-real-time/45119#45119)
- `Apr 28, 2014` : [MySQL (on Windows) general log too large to rotate properly?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64113/mysql-on-windows-general-log-too-large-to-rotate-properly/64114#64114)

Once you configure it, just run queries like this to see commands run today

```
SELECT user_host,argument
FROM mysql.general_log
WHERE event_time >= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND;
```